# In Real Analysis by Royden, chapter 11, section 4 proposition 17 why the domain of integration is not mentioned.

Tags: measure-theory

In the above said text book chapter 11, section 4, proposition 17 why the domain of integration is not mentioned.

Comment: Would you mind posting the actual proposition? I'm not going to (illegally) access the book in order to address the question and I'm not sure many others would either.

Comment: Probably because "it is understood"!

Comment: @CameronWilliams You needn't access it illegally. You might go to your university's library and get a copy! =D

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I might consider doing so if I was in the library already. However something tells me a 30 mile commute isn't quite worth it :P

Answer (score 1):

I've got the second and third editions of Royden in front of me and in both editions Proposition 17 is a convergence theorem with the following conclusion:
$$\int f\,d\mu \le\liminf\int f_n\,d\mu_n$$
If this is the integral in question, then the domain of integration is the entire space, which is the convention when there is no other indication of a set over which the integration must take place.